# unexplainable "<" and double output in jade include

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, include, pug

i am refactoring my page to have dynamic includes, pre-rendering them on the server, and passing them to `res.render()`

but now, there are `<` and `>` appearing on the page, and the include is rendered twice, which i cannot understand.

`routes/tips.js`

```
// ...

router.get('/addition/:number', function(req, res) {
    console.dir(renderTemplate(makePath('add/add' + req.params.number))); // shows just what i want, without extra characters
    res.render('tips/tipsLayout', {content: renderTemplate(makePath('add/add' + req.params.number))});
    // at this point, 'content' is definitely correct.
});

// ...
```

[image: this is correct]

`tipsLayout.jade`

```
extends ../layout
block content
    .wrapper.col-xs-12.col-md-12.col-lg-10.col-lg-offset-1
        h1= title

        a(href='/tips/', data-i18n="buttons.back")
        p(data-i18n="markup.tipsHeading")

        block extraJS
            script(src='/javascripts/tips.js', type='text/javascript')

        include tipsMenu.jade

        .tipContent
            #{content}  // here i want to insert pre-rendered 'content'
```

`tips/add/add0.jade`  (which is what gets pre-rendered)

```
- var path = "[html]hints.+.0."

h1(data-i18n=path + "0")
.tipsFrame
    .tipsText
        p(data-i18n=path + "1")
        p(data-i18n=path + "2")
        p(data-i18n=path + "3")
    .tipsExample
        p(data-i18n=path + "4")
        p(data-i18n=path + "5")
        p(data-i18n=path + "6")
```

html output:

```
// ...

<div class="tipContent">   // so it looks like it is something inside 'content' after all..?
    "<"
    <h1 data-18n="[html]hints.+.0.0">Addition from left to right (1)</h1>
    <div class="tipsFrame">...</div>
    ">"
    <!--<h1 data-i18n="[html]hints.+.0.0"-->     // note the comment here...(where does that come from?)
    <div class="tipsFrame">...</div>
    ">"
</div>

// ...
```

everything worked before, with the tips being included as normal `extend` / `block`s

[image: this is how it looks]

## update

i was thinking maybe it has to do with `block content` and `#{content}` having the same name, but i changed the latter and still the same output.

## update 2 & solution

ah well.. it looks like `#{content}` had to be `!{content}`....

Answer (score 1):

fount it..

`#{content}` => `!{content}` ...

and suddenly, all the errors disappear